# How can I close menu after click outside menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make hiding sidebar menu which will be opened whenuser click button. After that when user click outside menu - menu will be closed. How can I make this function in this case?

[***JsFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/t1nhdjkf/)

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

Comment: `document.body.addEventListener('click', closeNav);`

Answer (score 2):

You can react on a click on the entire document element and find out whether the target is located within your menu:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", function(e){

    if (e.button != 1) // left mouse
        return;        // anything else => do nothing

    var target = e.target;
    var navItem = document.getElementById("mySidenav");
    do{
        if (target == navItem)
           return; // clicked within "mySidenav" => do nothing
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    while(target != null);

   // react here     
   closeNav(); // must be implemented somewhere
});
```

It is desirable not to react at all if you detect that the click was indeed fired within your menu because otherwise you might close the menu before the click gets bubbled to the item => no menu item click detected.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}
function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
document.addEventListener('mousedown',function(event){
        var side_dom    = document.getElementById("mySidenav")
        if(side_dom.style.width == '250px'){
                if(!side_dom.contains(event.target)){
                        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
                }
        }       
})
```

```css
.sidenav {       
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;   
  top: 0;               
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</s
</body>
```